# Save an array to Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings (C# + WinUI3)

Tags: c#, arrays, save, winui

I just started learning WinUI 3 and I am currently trying to make a little todo app.
I want to save the data of the lists so I can keep it even if the application is closed.
Microsoft recommends using:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
```

And then using:

```
localSettings.Values["Datakey"]
```

to access the data.

This works well for data types like stings, ints etc. However, when I try to save an array that way, it gives me an error:

```
//Get data of the list boxes as save it to an array
string[] doneItems = lsbTasksDone.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
string[] undoneItems = lsbTasksUndone.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

//Save arrays to localSettings
localSettings.Values["ToDoDoneSaveData"] = doneItems;
localSettings.Values["ToDoUndoneSaveData"] = undoneItems;
```

Error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: "Incorrect size argument."

I couldn't really find any info on that error.

How do I save that array?

Regards,
LightJack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persists arrays into the ApplicationData class, however there are strict size limitations. Namely, entries cannot exceed [8KB in size or 64KB if using ApplicationDataCompositeValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings?view=winrt-22000&WT.mc_id=WDIT-MVP-5004239#remarks). The following code works:

```
localSettings.Values["Demo"] = new string[10];
```

while this fails as it is exceeding the space limitation:

```
localSettings.Values["Demo"] = new string[10000];
```